# How can I create a entity with a list of entities that has already been created

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, dto

I'm trying create a new entity (sale) with its attributes, one of them is a list of products that have already been created. When I try to save the sale with the repository I get a error

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Unique index or primary key violation: "PUBLIC.UK_PENFKDX7890EQY3I2RH0BA4WV_INDEX_4 ON PUBLIC.SALE_PRODUCTS(PRODUCTS_ID NULLS FIRST) VALUES ( /* 7 */ CAST(7 AS BIGINT) )"; SQL statement:
insert into sale_products (sale_id, products_id) values (?, ?) [23505-214]
```

Therefore, I realize that the error is because spring try to do the relationship between sale and product and sale doesn't has a id (is null). But the repository (SaleRepository) is supposed to generate the id, so I used the   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY).

I don't know what I should do, someone know how I can fix it?

code:

sale

```
@Entity
public class Sale {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String concept;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date created_at;
    private Double price;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    private Customer customer;
    @OneToMany
    private Set<Product> products;
 public Sale(){}

    public Sale(String concept, Customer customer, Set<Product> products) {
        this.concept = concept;
        this.customer = customer;
        this.products = products;
        this.price=0.0;
        onPrePersist();
    }

    @PrePersist  void onPrePersist() {created_at = new java.util.Date();}

    //get and setter
}
```

product

```
@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private Double price;
    private Integer amount;
    private String barCode;
    private String origin;

    public Product(){}

    public Product(String name, String description, Double price, Integer amount, String barCode, String origin) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.barCode = barCode;
        this.origin = origin;
    }
//get and setter
}
```

saleServiceImp (method where I create a sale)

```
   public SaleDTO save(SaleRegistrationRequest saleRegistrationRequest) {
        Sale sale= new Sale(
                saleRegistrationRequest.concept(),
                findCustomerOfSale(saleRegistrationRequest.customerDTO()),
                convertProductsDTOToProduct(saleRegistrationRequest.productsDTO())
        );
        LOGGER.info("SALE: "+sale.toString());
        saleRepository.save(sale);  // HERE FAIL!
        LOGGER.info("Sale saved successfully "+sale.toString() );
        return saleDTOMapper.apply(sale);
    }

    private Customer findCustomerOfSale(CustomerDTO customerDTO){
            return customerRepository.findById(customerDTO.id()).orElse(null);

    }

    private Set<Product> convertProductsDTOToProduct(Set<ProductDTO> productDTOS){

        if(productDTOS ==null || productDTOS.isEmpty())
            return null;

        return productDTOS.stream().map(productDTO -> {
            return iProductService.findProductById(productDTO.id());
        }).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
```

The error

```
2023-03-01 17:18:15.064 ERROR 8422 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Unique index or primary key violation: "PUBLIC.UK_PENFKDX7890EQY3I2RH0BA4WV_INDEX_4 ON PUBLIC.SALE_PRODUCTS(PRODUCTS_ID NULLS FIRST) VALUES ( /* 7 */ CAST(7 AS BIGINT) )"; SQL statement:
insert into sale_products (sale_id, products_id) values (?, ?) [23505-214]
2023-03-01 17:18:15.065  INFO 8422 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
2023-03-01 17:18:15.086 ERROR 8422 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["PUBLIC.UK_PENFKDX7890EQY3I2RH0BA4WV_INDEX_4 ON PUBLIC.SALE_PRODUCTS(PRODUCTS_ID NULLS FIRST) VALUES ( /* 7 */ CAST(7 AS BIGINT) )"; SQL statement:
insert into sale_products (sale_id, products_id) values (?, ?) [23505-214]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Unique index or primary key violation: "PUBLIC.UK_PENFKDX7890EQY3I2RH0BA4WV_INDEX_4 ON PUBLIC.SALE_PRODUCTS(PRODUCTS_ID NULLS FIRST) VALUES ( /* 7 */ CAST(7 AS BIGINT) )"; SQL statement:
insert into sale_products (sale_id, products_id) values (?, ?) [23505-214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:508) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:223) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:199) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.index.Index.getDuplicateKeyException(Index.java:525) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVSecondaryIndex.checkUnique(MVSecondaryIndex.java:223) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVSecondaryIndex.add(MVSecondaryIndex.java:184) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTable.addRow(MVTable.java:519) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:174) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:135) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.dml.DataChangeStatement.update(DataChangeStatement.java:74) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:169) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:252) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:209) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:169) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:46) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.recreate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1352) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionRecreateAction.execute(CollectionRecreateAction.java:50) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:344) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1407) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:489) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3303) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2438) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:449) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:562) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743) ~[spring-tx-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711) ~[spring-tx-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654) ~[spring-tx-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407) ~[spring-tx-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy108.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.api.store.service.SaleServiceImp.save(SaleServiceImp.java:43) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.api.store.controller.SaleController.save(SaleController.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1071) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:964) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:696) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

2023-03-01 17:23:29.979  INFO 8422 --- [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-03-01 17:23:29.979  INFO 8422 --- [ionShutdownHook] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed evictData of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
2023-03-01 17:23:30.191  INFO 8422 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-03-01 17:23:30.195  INFO 8422 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Process finished with exit code 130 (interrupted by signal 2: SIGINT)
```

Comment: Storing a list of products is a very poor design and additionally you **cannot** have that list defined as a FK  (relationship). You need to create another table something like sale_product where each row contains (sale_id,product_id). Search for and study *data normalization*.

Comment: Whe I use the OneToMany annotation, spring automatically create a new table (sale_product) where is saved the sale_id and product_id. I made this relationship (sale_product) unidirectional, the problems is when I add the products to the sale and the save the sale (using saleRepository to update the database).

Answer (score 0):

I had used wrong the relationship (annotation), I was using OneToMany I changed it for ManyToMany.
so, one product only can in one sale not in another sale.